# PYTHON 3.7 - export the result of a query DB to a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, export-to-csv

I recently started using python, and I'm trying to export the result of a query to a csv file, but without success.

```
id = 563;

try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT start_time,end_time FROM appointment WHERE box_id=%s", (id,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    with open('dataTester.csv', 'w') as fp:
        a= csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        for line in data:
           a.writerows(line)

    for row in data:
        print (row[0],row[1])
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
except:
    print ("error")

connection.close()
```

I have the following error:

iterable expected, not datetime.datetime

the error is at the line: `a.writerows(line)`

Comment: Add a `print(type(line), line)` just before the line the error is on, and maybe a `print(data)` after `data = cursor.fetchall()`. What you think you're getting from the query doesn't seem to be what you think you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the indexed elements of the result tuple. Try something more like this:

```
a.writerows(line[0], line[1])
```